# jquery ui autocomplete - server results not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

jQuery UI autocomplete is fetching valid json results from the server, but does not insert them into DOM / display in browser. When I embed the results in the page, autocomplete works as expected.

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    $('#query').autocomplete({
        source: '/ajax/abc',
        /*source: ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'],*/
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(e,ui) {
            $('#query').val( ui.item.value );
            $('form#search').submit(); 
        }
    });
```

JSON result from /ajax/abc (detected using Firebug):

> ["alpha","beta","gamma"]

Generated source from Firefox after typing "gam" into the input

(Server):

```
<ul style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" role="listbox" class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></ul>
```

(Embedded results):

```
<ul style="z-index: 1; top: 31px; left: 185px; display: block; width: 149px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" role="listbox" class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><li role="menuitem" class="ui-menu-item"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all">gamma</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a conflict with the jquery validation plugin which I had downloaded a few weeks ago. I'm not sure exactly what the conflict was, but I identified it by commenting out each script one at a time.

I downloaded the latest, minified version of jquery validation from CDN, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does your remote server return the correct header to allow this?

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

see this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html
The result returns a header with that in it.  This is needed for cross server calls.

Comment: perhaps i should not have used the word remotely. it is the local server. i just meant that it is calling the server rather than using the embedded results.

Comment: mime type needs to be this: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: still no results when i force that content type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the mime-type is wrong so that jQuery doesnt' handle the json as json.
Check the mime-type of your output json. It has to be 'application/json'

Comment: If you are using PHP set this in front of your output json: header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: still no results when i force that content type

Comment: What is the Output of your Script in Firebug? OK i have seen it in the text. Sry

Comment: Do you have a link to your page?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately, we are in stealth mode.

Comment: hm ok. not my problem. can you try to change your json like this: source: [{"value":"alpha","id":"alpha"},{"value":"beta","id":"beta"}]

Answer (score 0):

In worst case you can set a function as source. in this function you can give an array in response.
Also you can load your JSON in this function.

```
source: function(request, response) {
   /*
    * response is the typed text like 'gam'
    * request is the function that you have to call with the results
    */
   /* here your code */
   response(results);
}
```